# How to pass data back from multiple view controllers to root view controller using delegate? Ios 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, delegates, xcode5

My storyboard controllers: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LBEd.png

MenuViewController -> ChooseViewControler -> MapViewController and EditViewController.

I need to pass variable called address from MapViewController or EditViewController to MenuViewController. How i can implement this?

I try to use delegate, from this answer [Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers?answertab=votes#tab-top)
but dont understand, how to tell MapViewController or EditViewController that MenuController is its delegate before we push its on nav stack.

I do this at EditVC and its worked:

```
- (IBAction)OkButton:(id)sender {

    NSString *address = addressInput.text;
    MenuTableViewController *menuVC =
    [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [prevVC.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = address;

    [self.navigationController popToViewController:menuVC animated:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have the classes of these viewcontrollers as

MenuViewController.h,
MenuViewController.m

ChooseViewControler.h,
ChooseViewControler.m

MapViewController.h,
MapViewController.m

EditViewController.h,
EditViewController.m

There is this method called -**PrepareForSegue** called when you perform a segue either programatically(performSegue method) or by using push or model in navigation controller

implement this on your source ViewController (VC) ie, if you are passing from **MapViewController to EditViewController** ,
 Implement this in the **.m file of MapViewController**.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"toEditViewController"])
    {
        EditViewController *destinationVC=(EditViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
        destinationVC.address=self.address;
    }

}
```

Note that you have to identify the segue which is called by its name give in the storyboard

[image]

There many be many more segues you need to prepare...you need to do all this in the same method.

***identify the segue by name>prepare the methods***

Comment: Thank you for answer. I think segues is only using for pushing data forward.

Comment: you can also pass back

Comment: @ user3840005
if you change the address from editVC it will reflect in the object of  
MapViewController.address

Comment: Hmm. When I add push segue from editVC buttonOk to MenuVC, it broke all navigation bars.

Comment: You dont need to perform a segue here. The thing you want to do is to go back to the previous view controller in the navigation stack right? So you have to pop the view controller and go back.

You can either manually trigger the navigation backbutton.. or just pop the view controller.

Comment: I need to send text from UITextField on editVC to MenuVC cell.textLabel.text. Its not previous, its pre previous VC.

Comment: @user3840005 still you can do this...

You will have a flow of these VC's right?

ok, lemme assume it as 

Menu>Map>Edit

declare NSString *address for all of these 3 VC's

then when you push MAP
assign
MAP.address=MENU.address
then while moving from MAP to EDIT
do the same
EDIT.address=MAP.address,...

now 3 of these address variables point to the same NSString object.
so if you change MAP.address it will change EDIT.address,MENU.address

now..in

ViewDidAppear of MENU VC and EDIT VC method if you assign

textfield.text=_address OR self.address

you will have the new value in the textfield